# is WinForm a front end technology?

Tags: c#, winforms, frontend

I am not clear about one thing please, kindly confirm me.

Can we call C# Win-Form a front end technology or front end technology is meant only web based front end ( html, css etc) ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unless there's a specific definition I don't know about, I'd call it a front-end technology.  It's a UI technology for a given application, which can access shared back-end resources.

Comment: The term "Front End" to describe a User Interface has been around longer than the internet so it would not be meant only for web based technology. See [Databases: Artificial Intelligence breeds competition for established vendors](http://books.google.com/books?id=fS8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA29&#v=onepage&q&f=false) from a 1985 Info world article. Its got a great picture showing the Symantec Q&A UI with the caption "Q&A is a an integrated database/word processor with an AI-based front end"

Answer (score 7):

Front-end refers to user-facing UI, whether it's on a web browser, a desktop, or a smartphone.

Answer (score 4):

Back-end refers to stuff going on behind the scenes, i.e. not directly visible by the user, and front-end refers to the opposite - the stuff that's directly visible.

Hence, WinForms is clearly a front-end thing.

Answer (score 2):

Front-end technology can essentially apply to any technology that is primarily used to build applications' user experiences. This can include WinForms, Win32's windowing API's, MFC, Silverlight, Javascript, HTML, CSS. etc.

Comment: Javascript is not a front-end technology; it's just a language.  (see node.js)

Answer (score 1):

Winforms is a set of libraries for developing desktop user interface applications on .NET/Mono.

Comment: "...on windows" except when its [not on windows](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms)

Comment: yeah, except when it's on Mono. Thanks Conrad.